# how to add option (uninstall updates) into the app info

Tags: java, android

as the picture below 
Can I allow the user to do so with my app? I mean, ca we allow the user  to uninstall this update and restore to the previous version.

**dose this option handle by us pragmatically  if yes then how to do it ?**

i had try to run an app then i changed the the version Name and run again  then i  checked the app info and that option was not there.

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is only available for System Apps.

System Apps have a permanent base apk that is located under `/system/app/`, and unless you root the device and remove that apk, it is not possible to completely uninstall.  That is why The only option for System Apps is <kbd>Uninstall updates</kbd>, which will revert the app back to the factory version that came installed on the firmware.

If you choose <kbd>Uninstall updates</kbd> for a System App, after confirming that you really want to do this, it will revert to the factory version. Then, after the app is reverted back the factory version, in the Application Manager you will see that the Uninstall option is grayed out (disabled).

Apps that do not have a factory version, i.e. do not have an apk under `system/app/`, and were installed manually by the user, do not have this option.  The only option is to uninstall the app completely.

Answer (score 0):

Only system apps which comes by defult when you buy phone...can have that facility to uninstall the update...and when you uninstall update it will go to defualt version when you bought phone...you can not get that option for apps which are installed by user